# GCD of polynomial values over a box

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $f,g$ be two polynomials with integer coefficients and equal degree $r \geq 3$, and co-prime as polynomials. I am interested in the following question: what is the distribution of $\gcd(f(m), g(n))$ as $m,n$ vary over a box?

In particular, I want to count the number of pairs of integers $(m,n)$ with $|m|, |n| \leq X$ and such that $\gcd(f(m), g(n)) > X^2$.

In the special case I am interested in, $f,g$ are given by $f(x) = F(x,\alpha), g(x) = F(x,\beta)$ for a binary form $F$ with integer coefficients and degree $r \geq 3$, with $\alpha, \beta$ distinct integers having size at most $X$.